# Using bal format command to format a package

Tags: ballerina

Can we use `bal format` command to format a package. When I try to use this command ( `bal format hello_world`) to format a package it results in the following error.

> error: couldn't find an existing module by the name: hello_world

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command from the package root directory.  Once you are in the package root directory, you can run the command `bal format` to format the package, `bal format <moduleName>` to format a module and `bal format <filename>` to format a specific file